# Transactional in Spring test does not work

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I am using Spring transactions (@Transactional) within my test. Basically, I have a DAO layer where each method has a @Transactional on the method. Within the test class, if I don't specify @Transactional, I can see the data in the database (so the data is saved), otherwise adding at @Transactional on the class does not persist the data. However, once the test has ended the data is persisted.

Would you know why it is doing this?

Comment: So how would you go about it? I want the it to flush the changes, so I can view the data and then revert the changes.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `the class does not persist the data`? If your tests are being run transactionally, no changes from that transaction will be viewable *outside* of that transaction until it is committed. So if, for example, your test does `INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES (...)`, then attempting to query the state with an external connection manager / client (e.g. `psql`) will not show those changes. The changes should still be visible if you query using the connection manager that is creating those transactions, however.

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding the `@Transactional` annotation Spring will start a new transaction surrounding your test method and `@Before`, `@After` callbacks and when the test finishes the transaction will rolled back automatically.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx

Comment: How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: Try to set breakpoint before a test is finished, until the test transaction has not completed yet and try to check your data in DB at this moment.

Comment: For example, with the saveAndFlush method.

Answer (score 0):

Some code of your test class would be helpful, so I can just guess ...

How do you save the data in the database? If you use a `Repository.save(E Entity)` method then the changes will not be flushed to the DB. They will only be saved in he first level cache.

If you want to flush your data to the DB you should use an `TestEntityManager` in your test class and call the `persistFlushFind(E entity)` method to really flush your entity to the db.